# How to update JTable using values from an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, jtable

Hi I converted my arraylist into an array so I can use it to display its elements in a JTable but nothing is displaying. It is giving me an error (error is explained in code comments). I just want to have one column only which displays values from this array. Can someone guide me in the correct direction? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
private static class EnvDataModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Object age[];
```

...

```
    public EnvDataModel() {
        age=list.toArray();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {

            return "Age";
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            // Error message The method get(int) in the type ArrayList<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
            return list.get(age[row]);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `ArrayList` in the `AbstractTableModel` returns Column, please read tutorial about `JTable` how [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) works

2) you can change `ArrayList<Integer>` to the `Vector<Vector<Integer>>` or `Interger[][]`, then you don't need to define for `AbstractTableModel`, only use default contructor for `JTable`

[JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

or

[JTable(Vector rowData, Vector columnNames)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29)

3) add `Integer` value to the [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Comment: My arraylist only has one column, can i still do this, if so, how?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins please (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133523/use-arraylist-to-fill-a-jtable-in-java) are you joking

Answer (score 0):

`list.get(age[row]);` requires `list.get(int)` whereas `age[row]` is object.

So, try this

```
int i =Integer.parseInt( age[row].toString() );
```

and than

```
 list.get(i);
```

Comment: Print value of `list.get(Integer.parseInt( age[row].toString() ))`.?