# Java: how to make fireTableStructureChanged change an AbstractTableModel?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have made a custom AbstractTableModel. The constructor initialises the model with data from a file. However, I wish to add an extra column to the model (this is because of SQL limitations in its columns).

I seek to achieve this by adding to the initialisation code a call to an addColumn(String columnName, Vector columnData) method.

This addColumn method in my custom AbstractTableModel is derived directly from DefaultTableModel's addColumn method, including "fireTableStructureChanged()".

Yet when I run this code, fireTableStructureChanged() appears not to add my new Column and the JTable displays only with data from the file. Why might this be?

Here is a short indication of the code I am using:

```
public class Dummy extends AbstractTableModel {
    public Dummy() {
        //load data from SQL file into ResultSets
        //transfer ResultSet.metadata into columnHeaders Vector<String>
        //transfer ResultSet.data into columnDatums Vector<String>
        fireTableChanged(null);
        addColumn("Added Heading", (Vector)null);
    }

    public addColumn(String columnHeader, Vector columnData) {
         columnHeaders.add(columnHeader);
         // transfer columnData into columnDatums
         fireTableStructureChanged();
    }
 }
```

Is it a listener problem - is nothing listening at this point in time to fireTableStructureChanged()?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @kleopatra - thanks but I know them. dummy is no more than a throw-away class name for stackoverflow purposes!

Comment: it's hurting the eyes of potential helpers :-) Which can't be what you want ...

Comment: @kleopatra: so true! I've amended the code snippet. Lesson appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to reveal your implementation of the three *required* (i.e. *unimplemented*) methods specified by the `TableModel` interface in [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html). In particular, `getColumnCount()` and `getRowCount()` must return the updated values. The `fireXxx()` methods simply instruct the view to query the model via `getValueAt()`. The data has to be there waiting for `getValueAt()` to retrieve. [`EnvTableTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) is a simple example. Also, consider a more modern alternative to `Vector`, which includes possibly uneeded synchronization code.

Comment: +1 for your thoughtful and in depth response. I will review the methods and try to solve the issue in the way you suggest. If it works out I'll accept your answer. If I struggle, I'll append the code to the question. Many thanks

Comment: you were quite correct. I had to ensure getColumnCount() and getRowCount() returned updated values. Thanks for the great answer and insight.

Comment: You're welcome; glad it's working. For reference, see also [*When an Abstract Class Implements an Interface*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Comment: To all future readers - to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions in getValueAt(), I also had to adopt DefaultTableModel's "justifyRows()" method and refactor my columnData into a Vector of Vectors of Objects to use justifyRows().