# How to create with Java swing a dynamic list where for each element must be specified multiple parameters

Tags: java, swing, list

I have less experience with Java Swing and I want to create a dynamic list where for each element must be specified 2 parameters.

I have n elements, where the number n isn't known and depends on others procedures...

I want that for the n elements, a swing GUI shows n lines where each line on the left has 2 box for setting parameters *String id* and *int time*.

This swing GUI on confirm should put all these data in a `List<Process>`
(where the Process is simply an object defined by a *String id* and *int time*).

Comment: I forgive you if you help me ^^     :P

Comment: Here's a [two-column table with a custom model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

Comment: As this is a duplicate of [How to create dynamically a swing list with n row where for each row I put 2 data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058426/how-to-create-dynamically-a-swing-list-with-n-row-where-for-each-row-i-put-2-dat), this question may be deleted.