# How to create dynamically a swing list with n row where for each row I put 2 data

Tags: java, swing

I have less experience with Java Swing and I want to create a dynamic list where for each element must be specified 2 parameters.

I have n elements, where the number n isn't known and depends on others procedures...

I want that for the n elements, a swing GUI shows n lines where each line on the left has 2 box for setting parameters String id and int time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) with two columns, one for each data value?

There's a good tutorial on using tables at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

[image: JTable Example from docs.oracle.com]

Comment: Also consider [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) with custom renderer.

Answer (score 1):

By Using ArrayList You can :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayList2d<Type>
{
ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>>  array;

public ArrayList2d()
{
    array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>>();
}

public void ensureCapacity(int num)
{
    array.ensureCapacity(num);
}


public void ensureCapacity(int row, int num)
{
    ensureCapacity(row);
    while (row < getNumRows())
    {
        array.add(new ArrayList<Type>());
    }
    array.get(row).ensureCapacity(num);
}


public void Add(Type data, int row)
{
    ensureCapacity(row);
    while(row >= getNumRows())
    {
        array.add(new ArrayList<Type>());
    }
    array.get(row).add(data);
}

public Type get(int row, int col)
{
    return array.get(row).get(col);
}

public void set(int row, int col, Type data)
{
    array.get(row).set(col,data);
}

public void remove(int row, int col)
{
    array.get(row).remove(col);
}

public boolean contains(Type data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if (array.get(i).contains(data))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public int getNumRows()
{
    return array.size();
}

public int getNumCols(int row)
{
    return array.get(row).size();
}
}
```

Comment: I do believe the OP meant a `JList`.

Comment: @Jeffrey I am sorry..!:( I Couldn't able to meet your needs..!