# Fill JTable in Java using Web Service recieving a List<Project>

Tags: java, web-services, swing, collections, jtable

Hello I have a school project where we created webmethods using web service with an ordinary `.asmx` file.

The programs I made in .Net C# have no problem with the return being a `List<Project>`.
However, I try to get the Java to work, and I tried `Object[][] = wws.SelectAllProject()` and so forth.

Here's the webmethod:

```
  [WebMethod]//Ska vara collection
    public List<Project> SelectAllProjects()
    {
        Controller contr = new Controller();
        List<Project> project = contr.SelectAllProjects();
        return project;
    }
```

Here's the Project.cs file:

```
public class Project
{
public string pId { get; set; }
    public string pName { get; set; }
    public string pDescript { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        this.pId = pId;
        this.pName = pName;
        this.pDescript = pDescript;
    }
}
```

So in Java how shall I call the method?
**I can call my other methods that are void which are ADD/Remove project...**

```
public void SelectAllProjects () {
    WebService webService = new WebService();
    wws = webService.getWebServiceSoap12();
    //Anropar webservice och får en Collection av Project
    String[] columnNames = {"Project ID:", "Project Name:", "Project Description:"};
    Object[][] = wws.selectAllProjects();
    //Array[]test = wws.selectAllProjects();
}
```

Now I want to return something from this method (it should not be void) that which I can use to fill out a JTable in my view class (using MVC). The webmethod you see and returns a list of project. How shall I make this in Java? Tried googling, but I don't seem to find anything that is close to my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Compose your `TableModel` with a reference to your `List<Project>`, and use the model to construct your `JTable`. For example, your table might display two of the three project attribtes, and your row count would rely on the list's `size()`.

```
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return project.size();
}
```

For reference, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) `extends AbstractTableModel` and illustrates an implementation of `getValueAt()` that uses a `Map<String, String>`. See also [*How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Comment: this (linked example) Model is excelent I think

Comment: @mKorbel: Thanks to you, I have seen the virtues of `DefaultTableModel`, but I like the flexibility of choosing the data structure inside the `TableModel`.