# ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to String[][]

Tags: java, swing, jtable

It looks like the `JTable` construct likes `String[][]`... but I like to use smarter containers until I have to use something else. been using `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, now I need to make `JTable` happy with `String[][]`.

I found a real easy way to convert an `ArrayList<String>` to a `String[]` using `toArray()`, but not finding the easy converter for multidimensional arrays.

I want to go from `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to `String[][]` in the least number of lines.

I have been searching the library and cannot seem to find this converter, and hoping someone could suggest a good solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you should use `List<List<String>> matrixString`. I mean you should use the `List` instead of `ArrayList` to declare the variable. And the answer of Robert Rouhani is fine.

Comment: Both answers are so good, it makes it real hard to pick which one I think has the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to look at implementing your own table model:
[JTable(TableModel dm)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28javax.swing.table.TableModel%29)

You can create a class that extends AbstractTableModel and delegates to a List, or any other suitable data structure.

Comment: +1 agree; there's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

Comment: Even though you did not show how to convert the data, your answer points me in a much better direction, and for that, I believe you have the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` isn't contiguous in memory. That is the second array list stores an array of references to `ArrayList<String>`s, and in each of those ArrayLists, there can be an array larger than the amount of items you put into it.

So the only real way to do this is by iterating:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data;

//...

String[][] converted = new String[data.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < converted.length; i++)
    converted[i] = data.get(i).toArray(new String[data.get(i).size()]);
```

Comment: `ToArray()` should be `toArray(new String[data.get(i).size()])`

Comment: gah! I knew I'd run into an issue like that. I haven't touched Java in a few months in favor of C#... (I almost messed up `.size()` as `.Count`)

Comment: +1 Another way would be: `converted[i] = new String[data.get(i).size()];` - `data.get(i).toArray(converted[i]);`

Comment: You have reminded me about the non-contiguous memory storage....and for that...with the solution, I think this is a very good answer