# MVC Pattern and JTable's

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtable

I've implemented this MVC pattern into my system :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html

Everything is good and dandy, I have different views and they talk to the controller when they need to put changes into the model or get called upon when changes are reflected int he model.

Now, I need this new view which uses a JTable. I've decided to extend by model's as AbstractTableModels, now only am I not sure if this is right, but the Java website proposes this to bind the model to the table:

```
public TableDemo() {
    ...
   JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
   ...
}
```

This just feels wrong, I don't have a reference to my model in my view, so how am I supposed to give a model from my view to the JTable? I could create a ;getModel; method in my controller for this special case, but still I don't know if there's a better way to deal with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct; [`EnvTableTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) is an example. The table's `getModel()` method will return your `TableModel`. See also this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).