# Refreshing JTable when data has changed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, abstracttablemodel

I have a problem with refreshing a `JTable`. I start with an empty `ArrayList` and after setting my choice of a combo box I load content to the `ArrayList` but `JTable` does not react to it - it remains empty. Is it a problem with a `TableModel`?

This is my code...

```
public class ProjectTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static ArrayList<String> caseList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return caseList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt( int row , int col) {
        getRowCount();
        switch(col){
            case 0:
                System.out.println("mam to");
                return caseList.get(row);
        }   
        return null;            
    }


    public void setCaseList(String[] list){
        for (int i =list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            caseList.add(list[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(getRowCount());
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public String setValueAt(int row, int col){ 
        return null;
    }

    public void addTestCase(String name) throws IOException{    
        File newDir = new File(TestCaseMaker.currentDir, 
            "Przypadek testowy"+(caseList.size()+1));
        newDir.createNewFile();
        caseList.add(name);

        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return "Przypadki testowe";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `setValueAt()` is incorrect. It has the wrong signature, and it fails to notify its view.

Addendum: *My* `JTable` *does not react to any changes to data model*

For reference, [`EnvTableTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) is an example using `AbstractTableModel` that precludes editing; the default implementation of `isCellEditable()` always returns `false`.

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
    if (col == 1) {
        System.out.println("setValueAt: " + row + " " + aValue);
        // update caseList here
        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}
```

There's a related example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Comment: Just out of curiosity ... does the implementation of this method matters if you have a non-editable table model (non-editable as in no editor on the `JTable`). I would think this method is not called at all in that situation

Comment: Even though my JTable does not react to any changes to data model(changes of contents in ArrayList). I used a similar model found on the net in other project and it worked perfectly...