# Pass LinkedList from another class for JTable. Automatically update table

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, jtable, abstracttablemodel

So, I am currently building the GUI for my program. I am using JTables with a custom AbstractTableModel to fill them with the contents of my different LinkedLists. 
However, if I add a JTable to my GUI class, and initialize the LinkedList class there, then that is not the LinkedList that I need. I need the LinkedList Studentlist, which I have stored in my Database class. How do I tell the table that? 
I can't really show any GUI code, because it is all still in the making, and I am just testing things out at the moment.

My other question is, this is my AbstractTableModel:

```
public class StudentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

public static final String[] columnNames = { "ID", "First Name",
        "Last Name" };
private LinkedList<Student> data;

public StudentTableModel(LinkedList<Student> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnNames[column];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Student student = data.get(rowIndex);
    if (student == null) {
        return null;
    }
    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
        return student.getID();
    case 1:
        return student.getFirstname();
    case 2:
        return student.getLastname();
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Do I need to add anything to the code to make the table automatically update when a student is added to the list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum,

- As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113865/230513), you implementation of `setValueAt()` must fire an event *appropriate* to your update.
- If you expose a public method to mutate `data`, it too must fire an *appropriate* event.

In this context, *appropriate* means one of the `fireXxx()` methods inherited from [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to add anything to the code to make the table automatically
>   update when a student is added to the list?

Create a method in the `TableModel` such that when the Student is added then pass the Student object to the list and add it to the list. Since you are using `AbstractTableModel` you need to fire appropriate events after data change.

```
private void addStudent(Student student) {
    data.add(student);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

> if I add a JTable to my GUI class, and initialize the LinkedList class
>   there, then that is not the LinkedList that I need. I need the
>   LinkedList Studentlist, which I have stored in my Database class.

While you are creating table model then query for the StudentList and send that list to the table model constructor.