# Last row always removed from DefaultTableModel, regardless of index

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, defaulttablemodel

I face some problems when I am trying to remove rows from a table in java. In particular, I use the `DefaultTableModel`, and when I am trying to remove a row, using the `removeRow(int row)` method, the last row is removed, regardless what the `row` is. For example, let's say that we have six rows. When the `removeRow(0)` or `removeRow(2)` or `removeRow(5)` is called, the last row is always removed. Any idea, why this is happening?

Thanks

---update

When a particular cell of the jtable is pressed, the corresponding row should be removed.

```
    class TagsTableMA extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        int row = tagsJT.rowAtPoint(p);
        int column = tagsJT.columnAtPoint(p);

        if (column == COLUMN_DELETE_TAG){
            DocDialog docDialog = new DocDialog(parentMainJF, 
                                                true, 
                                                null, 
                                                "Please confirm...", 
                                                "Are you sure you want to delete the \"" + 
                                                tagsJT.getValueAt(row, COLUMN_TAG_NAME) +
                                                "\" tag?",
                                                DocDialog.TYPE_YES_NO);
            docDialog.show();
            int answer = docDialog.getAnswer();

            if (answer == DocDialog.YES)                                                
                    model.removeRow(row);
        }
    }   
}
```

--- update no2
Here is some code with my issue. I've removed some stuff that are irrelevant.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MainJF extends JFrame {

public MainJF(){
    this.add(createTagsTable());
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200,400));
}

 private JTable createTagsTable(){

    String[] columnNames = {"",          
                            "Tag",
                            "",
                            "",
                            ""};


    Object[][] data = new Object[10][columnNames.length];
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        data[i][COLUMN_CHECK] = false;
        data[i][COLUMN_TAG_NAME] = "Tag " + i;
        data[i][COLUMN_TAG_ID] = i;
        data[i][COLUMN_EDIT_TAG] = "edit";
        data[i][COLUMN_DELETE_TAG] = "delete";
    }

    model = new TagsSelectionTableModel(columnNames, data);
    tagsJT = new JTable(model);

    tagsJT.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    tagsJT.addMouseListener(new TagsTableMA());

    return tagsJT;
}


class TagsSelectionTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{

    public TagsSelectionTableModel(String[] columnNames, Object[][] data){
        super(data, columnNames);
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
        this.data = data;
    }

    private String[] columnNames;
    private Object[][] data;


    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return data[row][col]; }
}

  class TagsTableMA extends MouseAdapter{

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        int row = tagsJT.rowAtPoint(p);
        int column = tagsJT.columnAtPoint(p);

        if (column == COLUMN_DELETE_TAG){
            int irow = tagsJT.convertRowIndexToView(row);     
            model.removeRow(irow);
        }
    }
}


private JTable tagsJT;
private TagsSelectionTableModel model;   

private static int COLUMN_CHECK = 0;
private static int COLUMN_TAG_NAME = 1;
private static int COLUMN_TAG_ID = 2;
private static int COLUMN_EDIT_TAG = 3;
private static int COLUMN_DELETE_TAG = 4;


public static void main(String args[]) {
    new MainJF().setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: could you show the code you are using to remove a row?

Comment: Of course. I've just updated my first post with some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `row` obtained from `columnAtPoint()` is in *view* coordinates, while `removeRow()` assumes *model* coordinates. Quoting from the relevant [tutorial section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection):

> This distinction does not matter unless your viewed data has been rearranged by sorting, filtering, or user manipulation of columns.

If so, you will need to use `convertRowIndexToModel()`, described near the end of [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), which advises:

> When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates.

Also, consider using a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) instead of a `MouseAdapter`.

Addendum: Your implementation of `getValueAt()` continued to access the array supplied to the constructor, while the model's data was actually stored in the parent implementation. If you really need more control over the model's data structure, extend `AbstractTableModel`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237205/230513 */
public class MainJF extends JFrame {

    private JTable tagsJT;
    private TagsSelectionTableModel model;
    private static int COLUMN_CHECK = 0;
    private static int COLUMN_TAG_NAME = 1;
    private static int COLUMN_TAG_ID = 2;
    private static int COLUMN_EDIT_TAG = 3;
    private static int COLUMN_DELETE_TAG = 4;

    public MainJF() {
        this.add(new JScrollPane(createTagsTable()));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JTable createTagsTable() {

        String[] columnNames = {"0", "Tag", "2", "3", "4"};

        Object[][] data = new Object[10][columnNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i][COLUMN_CHECK] = false;
            data[i][COLUMN_TAG_NAME] = "Tag " + i;
            data[i][COLUMN_TAG_ID] = i;
            data[i][COLUMN_EDIT_TAG] = "edit";
            data[i][COLUMN_DELETE_TAG] = "delete";
        }
        model = new TagsSelectionTableModel(columnNames, data);
        tagsJT = new JTable(model);
        tagsJT.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        tagsJT.addMouseListener(new TagsTableMA());
        return tagsJT;
    }

    class TagsSelectionTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        public TagsSelectionTableModel(String[] columnNames, Object[][] data) {
            super(data, columnNames);
        }
    }

    class TagsTableMA extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            int row = tagsJT.rowAtPoint(p);
            int col = tagsJT.columnAtPoint(p);
            if (col == COLUMN_DELETE_TAG) {
                model.removeRow(row);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainJF().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I said, when debugging I can see that the row that `removeRow` takes, is the right one, but for some reason always the last row is removed. Thanks for the advices.

Comment: So, no sorting, filtering, shifting? Are you building via [`invokeLater()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)?

Comment: No, I am not. Please see my last comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11237205/1485158). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I guess you _could_ be invoking `removeRow()` on the wrong model; an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) might clarify.

Comment: Ah, your example wasn't deleting from the wrong model, it was displaying old data; more above. See also `Vector#removeElementAt()`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code of the `removeRow(int)` method of `DefaultTableModel`, it is clear that it will remove the row array at the corresponding index of the backing `Vector`:

```
 public void removeRow(int row) {
    dataVector.removeElementAt(row);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
}
```

(from java 6).

I can think of two possibilities:

1. you've extended the `DefaultTableModel` and have changed the implementation of this method.  (i doubt that this is the case - you probably would have admitted to this in your post)
2. you have a custom renderer for the table, which paints the cell data based on the cell's row index.

Comment: Also consider sorting, filtering, etc., mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11241218/230513).

Comment: Thanks for your reply
1. Actually, I've extended the `DefaultTableModel` but I have not changed the implementation of `removeRow(int row)`.
2. No, I don't use any `TableCellRenderer`

When debugging I see that the row that `removeRow` takes, is the right one, but for some reason always the last row of the model is removed.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the data you are putting into the model.

Comment: JLabels, icons, buttons, strings and integers are included. I override the `getValueAt(int row, int col)` method of `DefaultTableModel`. Could this cause the problem? When I remove it, it works great, but some other functionalities do not work, such as the edit one.

Comment: Yes. `getValueAt` is the key here.  This is similar to my point 2 in effect.  If you are always returning a value that incorporates the row index, you will always see contiguous values.