# <JTable>.getSelectedRow() is returning -1

Tags: java, indexing, jtable

I have written a "double-click" event on my `JTable`. My JTable, viz. myTaskTable is populated with a number of rows having multiple columns. I want the row index to be retrieved when I double click on one of the rows of the `JTable`. I am not sure why is it always returning me an index of -1 resulting in an exception. Am I am overlooking something? What could be going wrong?

This is how I am retrieving the index of the selected row from the `JTable` - myTaskTable

```
int selRow = myTaskTable.getSelectedRow();
```

Thank you!

**Edit**

Here is the code:

```
...
myTaskTable.addMouseListener(this);
...
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
 if(e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK)
 {
   if(e.getClickCount() == 2)
   {
     e.consume();
     int selRow = myTaskTable.getSelectedRow();
     System.out.println("GridReport double clicked on row="+selRow);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that your problem is in code that you've not shown us. Our abilities to guess about errors in code not shown is quite limited.

Comment: For reference, here's a workign [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11241218/230513).

Comment: What is the `e.consume()` for? Also, is the myTaskTable variable referring to the JTable that is in fact being displayed? For better help, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). This will require a bit of effort, but is often well worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the row index using the event, not the table selection:

```
final int selectedRowIndex = table.rowAtPoint(mouseEvent.getPoint());
// If the rows are sorted or filtered
final int modelRowIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndex);
```

`getSelectedRow()` would not work with multiple selected rows (multiple selections allowed), as it will always return ["the index of the **first** selected row"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to put `e.consume();` as the last statement?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
 if(e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK){
   if(e.getClickCount() == 2){
     int selRow = myTaskTable.getSelectedRow();
     System.out.println("GridReport double clicked on row="+selRow);
     e.consume();
    }
  }
}
```

normaly `e.consume();` is called when you are done with your reactive code. This clears dependencies of the Event, so it might also clear the selected Row.