# Updating Mysql row twice in a row with java results in an error

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Whenever I update(edit) a single row twice in a row, i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:730)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:473)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
at bicrijnmondcustomermanagement.DataView.EditActionPerformed(DataView.java:686)
at bicrijnmondcustomermanagement.DataView.access$400(DataView.java:18)
at bicrijnmondcustomermanagement.DataView$5.actionPerformed(DataView.java:366)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

This is the code in question, i have tried to look online but found no solution, so i turned to StackOverflow :P thank you all in advance.

```
private void EditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   try{
       int row = Table_customer.getSelectedRow();
    String TClick = (Table_customer.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
       String edit1 = lNaam.getText();
       String edit2 = lEmail.getText();
       String edit3 = lAdres.getText();
       String edit4 = lPlaats.getText();
       String edit5 = lPostcode.getText();
       String edit6 = lTelefoon.getText();
       String edit7 = lBedrijfsNaam.getText();

       String sql="update customers set naam='"+edit1+"',email='"+edit2+"',adres='"+edit3+"',plaats='"+edit4+"',postcode='"+edit5+"',telefoon='"+edit6+"',bedrijfsnaam='"+edit7+"'where KL_NR='"+TClick+"'";
       preparedStatement=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
       preparedStatement.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");
   TheRefresher();


   }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }finally {
try{ //Update_tableCustomers();
resultSet.close(); preparedStatement.close(); }
catch(Exception e) { } }


}
```

Ps. Also if i edit another row and return to the one previously edited it works just fine, the problem arises when I edit the same row twice in a row.

Comment: Which is line 686 in your method? Doing

`set naam='"+edit1+"'` 

puts you at risk of SQLInjection, better to  bind variables, e.g. 

`set naam = ?, email = ? "`
and then
`preparedStatement.setString(1,edit1);
preparedStatement.setString(2,edit2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you didn't select any row before this action.

```
private void EditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)        
{                                     

  try{
   int row = Table_customer.getSelectedRow();
   System.out.println("selected row : " + row);
   if(row < 0) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentDialog, "Must select row" ); 
      return;
   }
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line:

```
 String TClick = (Table_customer.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
```

Because the stack trace shows this:

```
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
```

So getValueAt is throwing an exception, probably because getSelectedRow is returning -1.

Check to make sure getSelectedRow is doing what you expect.

See this: [<JTable>.getSelectedRow() is returning -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664023/jtable-getselectedrow-is-returning-1)