# Calculating total value in JTable Column using new value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to calculate total value in index [0][2], previous value is 0, but I have replaced and display it with the calculation result “1/y”, and when I calculate total value, value that summed is previous value that containing “0”, this my code,

```
     //observation table
                                     //0             1        2    3      4      5     6                       
     titleColumn = new Object[]{"Time (Second)","Medicine", "1/y","x2", "X/Y", "Y^", "Error"};
                               //0   1    2   3   4   5   6
    allData = new Double[][]  {{1.0,1.02,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {2.0,0.667,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {3.0,0.367,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {4.0,0.278,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {5.0,0.237,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {6.0,0.187,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {7.0,0.155,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {8.0,0.156,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {9.0,0.142,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {10.0,0.111,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {11.0,0.12,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {12.0,0.097,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {13.0,0.099,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {14.0,0.089,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {15.0,0.079,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                               {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}};

    tableModelObservation = new DefaultTableModel(allData, titleColumn);
    tableObservation.setModel(tableModelObservation);
    int row,column,inputRow,inputColumn;

    //index [0][2] was replaced with calculation 1/y
    row = 0;
    column = 1;
    inputRow = 0;
    inputColumn = 2;
    double onePerY = 0;
    for(int a=0;a<allData.length;a++){
        onePerY = 1/allData[row][column];
        //is this the way to use getValueAt() and for indicating that the dependent cell has been change ?
        tableObservation.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
        tableObservation.firePropertyChange("1/y", inputRow, inputColumn);
        tableObservation.getModel().setValueAt(onePerY, inputRow, inputColumn);  
        inputRow++;
        row++;
    }    

    //calculation total 1/y, summing is still using previous value "0"
    row = 0;
    column = 2;
    inputRow = 15;
    inputColumn = 2;
    double totalOnePerY = 0;
    for (int a=0;a<allData.length;a++){
        totalOnePerY += allData[row][column];
        row++;
    }
    //displaying result in row index[15] and column index[2] 
    tableObservation.getModel().setValueAt(totalOnePerY, inputRow, inputColumn);
```

this column  values ”1/y” after calculation process
[image: column 1/y]

What should I do, to be able to summing it using new value ?
all the assistance that you gave, I would appreciate it, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in [`DependentColumn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513), you can calculate derived values in your implementation of `getValueAt()`. If a column on which the value depends is editable, be sure to fire an event indicating that the dependent cell has changed.

Addendum: *I’ve added my code with* `getValueAt()`, *but the result is the same.*

Absent your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) I'm guessing: I see that you access the `allData` array *after* you use it to construct and update the `DefaultTableModel`. I'm not sure about the goal of the exercise, but you probably wan't to update the array *before* doing so. `DefaultTableModel` uses `Vector` internally, and it ignores the array after construction completes.

Comment: thank you trashgod , I’ve added my code with getValueAt(), but the result is the same

Comment: @irwansyahazniel: I've elaborated above; a similar problem is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11223586/230513).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [`EnvelopeTableMode`](http://java-sl.com/envelope.html) which wraps original model and can provide grouping functions (SUM, COUNT, AVG...).

Comment: thank you for your advice yesterday StanislavL, my task should be collected tomorrow, it seems, no more time to start from the beginning, thank a lots StanislavL