# Using fireTableDataChanged to Update Table Data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two tables, and I'm trying to add the data from a record in one table to another table when that record is clicked on.

Currently when I click on the table the values are added to the clickedData but this data doesn't refresh in the table.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

class TableTest extends JPanel {
    JTable tbl1, tbl2;
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    public TableTest(){
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 30);
        Object[][] data = new Object[100][2];
        Object[][] clickedData = new Object[100][2];
        String[] columnNames = {"X", "Y"};

        //Initialise tables
        tbl1 = new JTable(data,columnNames);
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        DefaultTableModel myModel = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
                return false;
            }
        };
        tbl1.setModel(myModel);

        DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel(clickedData,columnNames);
        tbl2 = new JTable(model2);

        DefaultTableModel myModel2 = new DefaultTableModel(clickedData,columnNames){

            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
                return false;
            }
        };

        //Update Table Data
        tbl1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){
                int row = tbl1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
                int col = tbl1.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
                //basket[0] = row;
                clickedData[0][0] = tbl1.getValueAt(row,col);
                clickedData[0][1] = tbl1.getValueAt(row,col+1);

                //use fireTableDatachanged
                model2.fireTableDataChanged();

            }
        });

        initLayout(0,0,tbl1);
        initLayout(3,0,tbl2);
    }

    public void initLayout(int xlayout, int ylayout, JComponent component){
        gc.gridx = xlayout;
        gc.gridy = ylayout;
        this.add(component,gc);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`DefaultTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) uses `convertToVector()` internally, updating the `clickedData` array used to create `model2` does not change the content of the model's `dataVector`. As a result, `fireTableDataChanged()` notifies the listening `JTable`, but the model has not changed in the interim. Instead, update `model2` via `setValueAt()`, which will fire the correct event for you. A similar problem is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11241218/230513).

Also consider using a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) instead of a `MouseListener`.

Comment: Thank You, this fixed the problem