# Exporting XML File From Jtable

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtable

I want to export a `XML` file from a `JTable`. Also I want to Export `HTML` file From the same `JTable`

Thanks ,

Comment: Your question is short on details and specifics and may not be answerable as written. Please supply more detail about your problem, enough so that it may be answerable. Else I fear that this question may be closed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"Your question is short on details.."*  What question?  I missed it. :(  But since the OP is discussing what they want, I'll mention I want a pony, an ice-cream, and a trip to Disneyland.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You question lacks enough detail to do anything more than outline a simple approach. The data viewed by a `JTable` is stored in it's `TableModel`. Suppose your model looks like the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

```
private Map<String, String> data = System.getenv();
```

You can write an XML representation to `stdout` like this

```
Map<String, String> data = System.getenv();
XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));
e.writeObject(data);
e.close();
```

The [`XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) API shows how to write to a file. Conversely, `XMLDecoder` maybe used to reverse the process. See [*Long Term Persistence of JavaBeans Components: XML Schema*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence3/) for more.