# Trying to show hashmap value to a GUI in another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, hash, hashmap

Here's the problem:
I want to check all of my customer list. Hence i will use a hash map and output their ic num and their name. The output runs fine if I tried to use the terminal.

But now I want to output the result of those hash map, into a GUI

Here's my coding so far. You may skip right to action event for viewNumCust. That's where i tried to output the haspmap into a jtextarea.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class manageClientAccGui extends JFrame
{
ImageIcon image;
JLabel imgLabel,clientLabel,helloLabel,greetingLabel;
JButton createCustProfileButt,editClientAccButt,deleteClientButt,backClientButt,viewNumCust;
JPanel panel1,panel2,panel3,panel4,panel5,panel6,panel7;
JTextArea viewListCust;

public manageClientAccGui()
{

    super("Team Garoking Manage Customer");

    Container con = getContentPane();
    con.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    image = new ImageIcon("images/garokingLogo.jpg");
    imgLabel = new JLabel(image);

    clientLabel = new JLabel("Manage Client Account");
    clientLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    helloLabel = new JLabel("Hello! ");
    helloLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    greetingLabel = new JLabel("What would you like to do? ");
    greetingLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(viewListCust,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    JLabel empty = new JLabel("");
    JLabel empty1 = new JLabel("");
    JLabel empty2 = new JLabel("");
    JLabel empty3 = new JLabel("");
    JLabel empty4 = new JLabel("");

    createCustProfileButt = new JButton("Create Customer");
    editClientAccButt = new JButton("Edit Customer Details");
    deleteClientButt = new JButton("Remove Customer");
    viewNumCust = new JButton("View Number of Customers");
    backClientButt = new JButton("Back");
    viewListCust = new JTextArea();
    viewListCust.setEditable(false);

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(12,3));
    panel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(12,3,0,3));
    panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel5 = new JPanel();

    panel6 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    panel7 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

    panel1.add(imgLabel);
    panel1.setBackground(new Color(90,18,18));

    panel2.add(clientLabel);
    panel2.add(empty);
    panel2.add(createCustProfileButt);
    panel2.add(empty1);
    panel2.add(editClientAccButt);
    panel2.add(empty2);
    panel2.add(deleteClientButt);
    panel2.add(empty3);
    panel2.add(viewNumCust);    
    panel2.add(empty4);
    panel2.add(backClientButt);
    panel2.setBackground(new Color(90,18,18));

    panel6.add(helloLabel);
    panel6.setBackground(new Color(90,18,18));

    panel7.add(greetingLabel);
    panel7.setBackground(new Color(90,18,18));

    panel3.add(panel6);
    panel3.add(panel7);
    panel3.setBackground(new Color(90,18,18));
    panel3.add(scrollPane);

    panel5.add(panel3);
    panel5.setBackground(new Color(90,18,18));

    panel4.add(panel2);
    panel4.setBackground(new Color(90,18,18));

    con.add(panel4, BorderLayout.WEST);
    con.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    con.add(panel5, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Action act = new Action();

    createCustProfileButt.addActionListener(act);
    editClientAccButt.addActionListener(act);
    deleteClientButt.addActionListener(act);
    backClientButt.addActionListener(act);
    viewNumCust.addActionListener(act);

    setVisible(true);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setLocation(((dim.width-1024)/2), ((dim.height-650)/2));
    setSize(1024,650);

}

//  public static void main(String args[])
//  {
//      new manageClientAccGui();
//  }

class Action implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {   
            if(e.getSource() == createCustProfileButt)
            {
                dispose();
                new Log("Accessing create customer");
                new addCustGui();
            }

            if(e.getSource() == editClientAccButt)
            {
                dispose();
                new Log("Accessing edit customer");
                new editCustGui();
            }

            if(e.getSource() == deleteClientButt)
            {
                dispose();
                new Log("Accessing remove customer");
                new removeCustGui();
            }

            if(e.getSource() == backClientButt)
            {
                dispose();
                new Log("Accessing main menu");
                new menuGarokingGui();
            }

            if(e.getSource() == viewNumCust)
            {
                int enumer = 0;
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                try
                {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("IndividualDetails.txt"));

                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");
                        map.put(columns[1,], columns[2])
                        enumer++;
                    }
                }catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                    }
                    new Log("View latest");
                    viewListCust.append("The clients are : " + map.values());
                    viewListCust.append("The total number of clients are : " + enumer);         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Change `}catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                    }` to `}catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                    { ex.printStackTrace();
                    }` and report the output. 2) Potentially long running tasks such as file I/O should not be done in the EDT.  Instead use a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Also consider `JTable`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

Comment: thank you andrew and trashgod. I am currently learning about printstacktrace (im fairly new to GUI). And for the record, my list of customers wont grow that much but i know what u mean. Currently looking at swing worker

Comment: @SalehinSuhaimi Make sure you mark an answer as accepted if one solved your issue. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map#values` returns a `Collection` of objects.

Calling `viewListCust.append("The clients are : " + map.values())` is simply going to call the `Collection#toString` method of the returned collection, which isn't likely to provide a pretty view of the contents.

Instead, you're going to have to iterate the collection yourself.

```
viewListCust.append("The clients are :");
for (String value : map.values()) {
    viewListCust.append("\n" + value);
}
```

Now remember, while you're reading the file and append the content, you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, this will make your program look as if it's hung.

You might like to take advantage of a `SwingWorker` to load the file in the background before updating the UI.  Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: im quite new to the GUI so ill take a look at swingworker right now. but before that, i tried ur coding and it says that i cannot see the map.values in the line 'for (String value : map.values) {' it says that the field AbstractMap<String,String>.values is not visible?

Comment: You need to replace the two lines under `new Log("View latest");` in the action performed method...

Comment: I did replaced it under the log. And i got the error. Perhaps the values are by default private?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, typo. The `for-loop` should read `for (String value : map.values()) {`. Updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much. Its running great now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate `viewListCust` before passing it to the `JScrollPane` like so:

```
viewListCust = new JTextArea();
viewListCust.setEditable(false);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(viewListCust,
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
```

`viewListCust` is currently null when you pass it into the `JScrollPane` constructor.

Comment: i did instantiate it, the coding is just messed up :) or did i miss something?

Comment: You instantiated it AFTER you created the JScrollPane. You need to do it before. In other words, just copy your viewListCust code and paste it before where you create the scrollPane (in the order I have shown).

Comment: Ah i forgot it must be in order. Thank you very much