# Display values inside a JList -

Tags: java, swing, model, hashmap, jlist

I have a method that returns a `HashMap`, and is defined as follows;

```
public HashMap<Integer, Animal> allAnimal(){

      return returnsAHashMap;
   }
```

`Animal` will have the following values in its class:

```
public Animal{

int animalID;
String animalName;

// i have declared getters/setters
}
```

I have a GUI screen which has a `JList` and it's defined as:

```
l = new JList();
l.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {

        String[] v = new String[] {"animal id 1", "2", "3"};
        public int getSize() {
            return v.length;
        }
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return v[index];
        }
    });
```

What I want to do is to display the AnimalID's in the JList. I need to find a way to call the `allAnimal()` method and display all its Animal Id's in the `JList`. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
public int getSize() {
    return allAnimal().size();
}
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return allAnimal().keySet().toArray()[index];
}
```

or can try:

```
        String[] v = null;
        v = allAnimals().keySet().toArray(v);
        public int getSize() {
            return v.length;
        }
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return v[index];
        }
```

Comment: Consider re-factoring the invocation of `toArray()` to avoid repeated calls.

Comment: But, how could i replace this line `        String[] v = new String[] {"animal id 1", "2", "3"}; With all the Animal Id's ?
`

Comment: @trashgod Like how he has done in the post or is there some other way to do it ?

Comment: Thank you.Is there a way, i could get the selected Value in the JList ?

Comment: I think you can get selected index easily, then you can get selected Id (for example using `getElementAt()`), then using allAnimals map, you can get value by `map.get(id)` method(if this is what you asked)

Answer (score 1):

Your `AbstractListModel` is anonymous, so first promote it to a named class, e.g. `MyListModel`. Then add a method to `MyListModel` that either accepts a `Map` or calls `allAnimal()` to obtain one. Once you have a reference to the `Map` in your model, you can convert the `keySet` to an array, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513), and use the keys to `get()` each `Map` entry in `getElementAt()`. Optionally, sort the array using `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: It's not clear what your keys represent; you may be better off iterating over the `entrySet()`. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows a _small_ number of typical `Map` entries.