# Make a Table from a TimeSeriesCollection

Tags: java, jtable, jfreechart, tabular

I have all of my data stored in a TimeSeriesCollection, and instead of making a graph with the data, I want to have the option of presenting the data in a table. The goal is to make it look something like this:

```
Name        5/1/2013    5/2/2013    5/3/2013
-------------------------------------------
Rick        12          0           82 
Dale        1           0           0
Shane       0           0           159
```

How should I go about this? How do I get the data I want out of the TimeSeriesCollection?

I need to make a column for every possible X value in the series. Something like 5/2/2013 needs to show up, even though there is no data for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a `TableModel` around your `TimeSeriesCollection`, although it might be more practical to transpose the table, identifying rows with the longer dimension. Your implementation of `getValueAt()` can fill in missing data as needed. For reference, this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) `extends AbstractTableModel` to return values from a `Map<String, String>`.