# Read files and insert data count into JTable

Tags: java, swing, io, jtable

How to read files and insert data count into `JTable`?

I have n number of text files. What I need to do is to read data from each file and insert the data count of each corresponding file into Java table such that:

```
File Name          Total records exist
-----------------------------------------
x1.txt                    457
x2.txt                    876
.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
xn.txt                    345
-----------------------------------------
Total                     1678
-----------------------------------------
```

Can you please help me out with some ideas to achieve the same?

Comment: *"Can you please help me out with some ideas to achieve the same?"*  1) See [Starting Writing a Program](http://home.earthlink.net/~patricia_shanahan/beginner.html) for great tips. 2) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I am trying with Hashmap, taking buffer-reader and increasing the count as every line is read, then trying to put the final count value in hashmap.

Comment: *"I am trying.."* Explain better with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Where is the code you havea tried with?

Answer (score 1):

Arrange for your read method to accept a `File` and return a `Map<String, Integer>`.

```
private Map<String, Integer> readData(File file) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    // fill in the map from the file
    return map;
}
```

Once you have the `Map`, you can build a `TableModel` around it, as shown in this [`EnvTableTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

```
private static class FileDataModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private Map<String, Integer> data = readData(file);
    private String[] keys;

    public FileDataModel() {
        keys = data.keySet().toArray(new String[data.size()]);
    }
    ...
}
```