# How to loop data into a JTable with a JComboBox from from an Arraylist<classType> which contain another arraylist?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, jcombobox

I realize that the title probably seems very confusing, so I am gonna try give an example.

I have a JTable, which i wish to populate an ArrayList of a custom object called rapport.

The rapport object contains: int Number, String caseName, ArrayList, ArrayList, int fee.

So the headers for the JTable looks as following: Number, caseName, appendix , outlay, fee.

So for each rapport in the ArrayList i want a new row with the attributes from the rapport, and the two cells with arraylists is gonna be shown in a JComboBox.

I know to use cellEditor to make specific coloums to contain a JCombobox, but i have no idea's how to load the data from an ArrayList as described.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `new JComboBox(list.toArray())`

Comment: @Arend: I inferred that he already knows how to "make specific columns contain a `JCombobox`". I'm guessing he needs a `TableModel` built around the `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Extend `AbstractTableModel` and include your `List<Rapport>`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) for a `Map<String, String>`. Use the resulting model to construct your table. Each element of the list will be one row, and each column for that row will be a corresponding field in an instance of `Rapport`.