# Populate a jTable from an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, arraylist, jtable

I'm trying to populate a `JTable` from an `ArrayList`, The `ArrayList` is filled with data from my database.

this is the code I tried :

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"Numéro d'ordre", "Article", "Quantité", "Remarque"});
        for (gestionstock.LigneBonInterne o : listLigneBonInterne) {
            model.addRow(new String[]{o.getNumOrder().toString(), o.getdesgArt(), o.getQte().toString(), o.getRemarque()});
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }

        jTable1.setModel(model);
```

But I get this error message :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at magasinier.BonInterneDetails.(BonInterneDetails.java:63)

the ligne 63 is : `jTable1.setModel(model);`

I did a test to see if the `ArrayList` is filled, and I found that the `ArrayList` is filled with records which means that there is no problem with filling the `ArrayList`

How can I solve this problem ?

## EDIT :

I tried to create the `JTable` using code and assign it to `ScrollPane` :

```
JTable jTable1 = new JTable(model);
        jTable1.setModel(model);
         jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
```

But I still get the same error this time is the line  : `jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);`

Comment: So now your jSCrollPane1 variable is null. You'll want to work this out.

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) built on `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: So, have you actually called `initComponents` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the `JTable` `jTable1` prior to setting the `TableModel`

```
jTable1 = new JTable(model);
jTable1.setModel(model);
```

Comment: I can't do that, I'm using netbeans.

Comment: @user2417302 I don't see how your choice of editor affects the code.

Comment: @chollida in netbeans I created the jTable by drag and drop from the palette, so the jTable is protected from changes I make to him.

Comment: I tried to create the jTable using code, and I did the same as in your post but I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: @user2417302 Can you ensure that you call `initComponents` before calling your code? This will instantiate your code. (This is why coding by hand gives you more freedom with the code.)

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans palette you can specify some custom post-initialization code or use a custom constructor.