# How to create a method to add a table

Tags: java

I have this question.

I have the following method:

```
    public static Object[] czyDziala(String[] lista) throws IOException {

        for(int i=0 ; i<=lista.length-1;i++){
            URL url = new URL(lista[i]);
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int len = httpCon.getContentLength();
            if (len>0){

                System.out.println(url +new String(" Site Work"));

            }else{
                System.out.println(url +"Site Don't Work");

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The argument in the method is a list of strings.

```
    JFrame okno = new JFrame();
    okno.setSize(1200, 500);
    okno.setVisible(true);
    okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    String [] col = {"Nazwa Witryny"};
    String [] listaWitryn = {"http://www.wp.pl",
                             "http://www.onet.pl","http://mobidev.pl"};


    try {
        Work.czyDziala(listaWitryn);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I add a table that is

> | Sites Name | Status |

I think that it is wrong method created? 
But I could be wrong.

Comment: Well currently your `czyDziala` method just returns `null`, always. You should probably change it to return a `boolean[]` indicating which sites "work" and which don't. Or change your code to a `checkSite` method taking a *single* site and returning a *single* value.

Comment: With the JTable class you can display tables of data: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Could I write this code?

Comment: tabla is a different word entirely :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be:

```
public static Map<String, Boolean> czyDziala(String[] lista) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Boolean> saveInDBList = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    for(int i=0 ; i<=lista.length-1;i++){
        URL url = new URL(lista[i]);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        int len = httpCon.getContentLength();
        if (len>0){

            System.out.println(url +new String(" Site Work"));
            saveInDBList.put(lista[i], true);
        }else{
            System.out.println(url +"Site Don't Work");
            saveInDBList.put(lista[i], false);

        }
    }
    return saveInDBList;
}
```

and

```
String [] col = {"Nazwa Witryny"};
    String [] listaWitryn = {"http://www.wp.pl",
                             "http://www.onet.pl","http://mobidev.pl"};


    try {
        Map<String, Boolean> saveInDBList = Work.czyDziala(listaWitryn);
        //Your Insert DB call
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: And how I display sites and status on the Jtable?

Comment: Pls refer this link 1) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212197/create-the-hashmap-based-on-jtable