# .ods spreadsheet to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, ods, odftoolkit

How can I view a sheet from .ods file in JTable? I'm using odftoolkit simple api and that's how I open the file

```java
      String filepath;
      if (openfile.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        filepath = openfile.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            doc = SpreadsheetDocument.loadDocument(filepath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    Locale.getString("fileError.message"),
                    Locale.getString("fileError.title"),
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
```

At this time I get every row with `doc.getTableList().get(0).getRowList()`. How could I turn every row into array?

Comment: What type does `doc.getTableList().get(0).getRowList()` return? I'm pretty sure it provides some method that will let you make an array of it.

Comment: Is there Javadoc for their API? Have you tried reading it?

Comment: `getRowList()` returns a list of `Row` and I found no useful method in `Row` class. Maybe I'm stupid, maybe not ;D
Sure there is. No, I've just googled a little bit.

Comment: read Oracle tutorial, How to use Tables part Creating a Table Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How could I turn every row into array?*

Don't. Instead, build a `TableModel` that implements the essential methods, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513), using the methods provided by the [ODF](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/) [API](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/mvn-site/0.8-incubating/simple-odf/apidocs/index.html).

```
@Override
public String getColumnName(int col) {…}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {…}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {…}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {…}
```

Comment: Sounds complicate to me. Will try and report some info :)