# How to do getValueAt() when using an AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I'm trying to make an program that shows all files in the temerary folder using an AbstractTableModel but how do i code the getValueAt() method.
The names of the files should be in the first column and the file path should be in the second column.
I nulled it for now but can someone show me hoe i should code it?

This is what i got so far:

```
public class UI extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable table;
File[] dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")).listFiles();

public static void main(String[] args) {

public UI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 542, 422);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 526, 384);
    contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Temp Files", null, panel, null);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    final AbstractTableModel myAbstractTableModel = new AbstractTableModel() {

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return dir.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return null;
        }


    };

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 402, 334);
    panel.add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    table.setModel(myAbstractTableModel);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `arg0` is the `row` and `arg1` is the `col`, so `dir[arg0]` is the `File` for each `row`. In your implementation of `getValueAt()`, return `file.getName()` or `file.getPath()` as indicated by the `col` value. [`EnvTableTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) is a related example that uses the more descriptive parameter names.