# Generic way to give a table model a list of objects

Tags: java, swing, list, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Is there a way to make a generic table model that take a list of object and present them in the jtable.
i can make a transfer object that has an array of strings define table column and a list of object then use reflection on the object to get the fields data to be presented in the table, but is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then use reflection on the object to get the fields data to be presented in the table

This is the way the [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) works.

> but is there a more efficient way?

Then you need to create a custom model. Check out the `JButtonTableModel.java` from the above link. It shows the minimal amount of code you would need to create a custom model.

Both of the above examples extend the functionality of the `Row Table Model` which is used to provide the generic Object storage and provide common model functions like add, remove.

Comment: +1 `BeanTableModel` looks like a more accessible example of class literals than the one I originally cited.

Answer (score 1):

Extend [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and make the enclosed data structure generic in whatever way suits your use-case. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) wraps a `Map<String, String>`, but you can also use [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html), as is done in [`DbUtils`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-commons-dbutils/info) and `BeanTableModel`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18859234/230513).