# How to convert JTable Vector to JTable ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, defaulttablemodel

How can I convert `JTable` `Vector` to `JTable` `ArrayList`? I changed all vector to arraylist, but I see some issue in calling `DefaultTableModel`. I have problem in converting the `ArrayList` to 2D array. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
String headers[] = {"Pick Columns"};
rows = new ArrayList<String>();
columns = new ArrayList<String>();
 addColumns(headers, columns);
tabModel = new DefaultTableModel(convertTowDArray(rows.toArray()), headers); 
table = new JTable(tabModel);
```

Here are the methods:

```
private Object[][] convertTowDArray(Object[] toArray) {
        Object[][] o = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < toArray.length; i++) {
            o[i][0] = toArray[i];
        }
        return o;
    }

public void addColumns(String[] colName, List<String> col)// Table Columns
    {
        col.addAll(Arrays.asList(colName));
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to do? it isn't clear

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to convert existing data into the form prescribed by the `DefaultTableModel` constructors, extend `AbstractTableModel` and let your implementation of `getValueAt()` access your data structure(s) directly. Simple examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg).