# Building JTable from ArrayList<T>

Tags: java, swing, jtable, gson

I am goint to write a method, say `public static JTable getJTableFromArrayList(ArrayList list)`, that can easily build a JTable from ArrayList to compare various of datas. **This ArrayList is supposed to held any type of Object**.

What I can come up with now is to use Gson.

1. Use `Gson.toJsonTree(Object src)` method to parse the `ArrayList<T> src` into a `JsonElement`.
2. Build `JsonObject[]` from the `JsonElement`
3. Use `JsonObject.entrySet()` to get a `Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>>`
4. Then build the `JTable` from a self-defined `AbstractTableModel`, while the row s and columns and titles are got from the `Set`.

Before I start it, I want to know if there is a simpler and more direct way to do this rather than play with Gson? And also, if others have accomplished this already, I would be glad to use ready-made tools.

Comment: `This ArrayList is supposed to held any type of Object.` - Your update doesn't change my answer.

Comment: @camickr what about the update just now? I haven't checked `Row Table Model`, I shall do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what GSON is but I don't think you need to convert your data.

You can use a TableModel that uses an ArrayList to hold custom Objects.

The [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) does most of the work for you. You will just need to implement a couple of methods (instead of creating an entire TableModel) to identify the columns of data that you want to see from your custom object. The `JButtonTableModel.java` source is a complete example that shows how you might do this.

> I don't know how to get the field names

Then maybe you can use the [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) which does all the work for you and uses reflection to create the TableModel.

Comment: I knew that some other guys should have done this already, I read the page and the models seems rather good. Now I will have to change the `T` to a bean, but this is really not a problem. I hope I can up these answer 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513), let your `TableModel` *contain* the `Map` and use the `keySet()` to index the rows in your implementation of `getValueAt()`.

Comment: I didn't make it clear to you. I know how to do the `TableModel`, I just wonder if I can do step 1-3 easier.

Comment: @bijiDango Could you please explain why it is necessary to convert to Gson to display the elements in a table? This would be interesting for me.

Comment: It is because gson would bring me a Map, that contains the field names and their datas in a class. An I don't know other ways to do it.

Comment: @bijiDango: Can you access `List<T>` directly to implement `getValueAt()`?

Comment: T is a arbitrary type, not a certain one.

Answer (score 1):

> Use Gson.toJsonTree(Object src) method to parse the ArrayList src into a JsonElement.

Just adapt the `ArrayList<T>` to the `TableModel` instead of converting the list to Gson.

> Use JsonObject.entrySet() to get a `Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>>`

A `TableModel` needs it's elements in a predictable order, because it can access them by the row index. Thus you have to find a way how to map the row indexes to the set's elements. But if you just adapt the `ArrayList` to the `TableModel` this will also be no issue.

It seems that you are looking for a `TableCellRenderer`, because you said that you want to display arbitrary objects the way like Gson creates the element tree. So I would implement it this way:

```
class JsonTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

   private String[] propertyColumns;
   private Gson gson;

   public JsonTableCellRenderer(String... propertyColumns) {
    this.propertyColumns = propertyColumns;
    gson = new Gson();
   }

   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(value);
    if (element instanceof JsonObject) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) element;
        String propertyName = propertyColumns[column];
        JsonElement propertyElement = jsonObject.get(propertyName);
        String propetyValue = propertyElement.toString();
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, propetyValue, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    }
        // implement this behavior, e.g throw exception
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: The problem is I am facing several `ArrayList` and different `T`. I don't know how to get the field names and there many other problems. It won't be problem if I just want to show a certain ArrayList in Jtable.

Comment: @bijiDango ok so your problem is that you want array lists with arbitrary object types to be displayed in the JTable. The way they get displayed is controlled by a `TableCellRenderer`. Why not implementing a `JsonTableCellRenderer`? I updated my answer.

Comment: Camickr's `Bean Table Model` is exactly what I want. You method is good though. But here you need `String... propertyColumns` to function well.