# How to set the PATH environment variable for JVM

Tags: java, maven, path, jvm, java-7

I am trying to run executables which are installed on my system with the Java 7 ProcessBuilder. I noticed that the environment variable PATH, which is available via

```
 System.getenv("PATH");
```

does not include my own, custom set path. It returns this:

```
 /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

My path looks like this:

```
 /Users/saschaf/.bin:/Users/saschaf/Entwicklung/spring-roo-1.2.4.RELEASE/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/saschaf/Entwicklung/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/saschaf/Entwicklung/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/saschaf/node_modules/.bin:/Users/saschaf/Entwicklung/git/tools:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I don't know how to set the PATH variable so that the JVM uses the correct one. Whats the problem here?

I am running the latest OS X Mavericks, JDK 1.7.0_25-b15, Maven Apache Maven 3.1.1.

Comment: I'd prefer instead of putting them into your PATH or setting the PATH from your program to just execute the programs by their absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) :

You can run the JDK just fine without setting the PATH variable, or you can optionally set it as a convenience. However, you should set the path variable if you want to be able to run the executables (javac, java, javadoc, and so on) from any directory without having to type the full path of the command. If you do not set the PATH variable, you need to specify the full path to the executable every time you run it, such as:

```
% /usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin/javac MyClass.java
```

To find out if the path is properly set, execute:

```
% java -version
```

This will print the version of the java tool, if it can find it. If the version is old or you get the error java: Command not found, then the path is not properly set.

To set the path permanently, set the path in your startup file.

For C shell (csh), edit the startup file (~/.cshrc):

```
set path=(/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin )
```

For bash, edit the startup file (~/.bashrc):

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:
export PATH
```

For ksh, the startup file is named by the environment variable, ENV. To set the path:

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:
export PATH
```

For sh, edit the profile file (~/.profile):

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:
export PATH
```

Then load the startup file and verify that the path is set by repeating the java command:

Comment: That is what I tried. AFAIK OS X uses the .bash_profile for environt variables, but I also tried .bashrc and .profile, to no avail. I'd like everyone of my colleagues to use their existing PATH settings, but this may not be possible. For now, I have configured the PATH variable in my IDE and will advise my colleagues to do so, too.

Comment: Yes that could be any of the Bash startup files -- ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile. setting it in IDE is probably the fastest way but then again it wont work out of the IDE unless you provide the absolute path. for the same reason its recommended to set these variables in bash start up files.

Comment: if you found my answer helpful, please do not forget to vote up or accept.

Comment: Setting the PATH in the bash startup files is out of the question, we do that already. I noticed another thing: I have to restart IntelliJ IDEA 12 after I set the path in a run configuration - weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your shell's `$PATH` as a command line parameter:

```
$ java -DPATH=$PATH -cp …
```

You can use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) to examine your environment.