# LinkedLists and AbstractTableModels

Tags: java, linked-list, jtable, tablemodel, abstracttablemodel

I'm still working my way through Java, and am currently having an issue with my AbstractTableModel implementation.

At present I have a group of LinkedLists such that a Menu has a LinkedList of Courses, and each Course has a LinkedList of Meals.

What is the most effective means, if possible, of displaying a JTable containing all the meals, with Menu being passed through as a parameter? All my trouble seems to be resting on the row count, as this can at best be set on the number of different courses. If the number of meals on each of these menus differs in length, as the getValueAt counts through, I'm being thrown an error.

Comment: Create an ArrayList containing all the meals of all the courses of the menu, and base your AbstractTableModel on this ArrayList.

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).