# Netbeans GUI Builder Displaying Elements in JTable From Linked List

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am using the Netbeans GUI builder to create a desktop Java application. I have a linked list that holds a bunch of objects. I was wondering if there was a way to create a JTable in the Netbeans GUI Builder and have it traverse through my linked list and write various fields of the objects at each node to rows in the table.

Obviously, there will be a variable amount of objects in the linked list, so I would also need a way to have this table dynamically adjust its size based on how many elements it is holding.

Lastly, I would like to be able to select a row in the table (Just one full row only. No multi-select. No only selecting one cell in the table etc.) and extract the data that is in the selected row.

Is there any way to do these things with a JTable in Netbeans? Or should I use a different Swing element for what I want to do? I am open for suggestions.

This is what my table looks like now -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWCKW.png
There is lots of blank space that I need to get rid of, hence the dynamic part mentioned above.

Comment: Have Netbeans do it, no, have you do it, yes, see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).  *"I would like to be able to select a row in the table (Just one full row only. No multi-select"* - Take a look at [`JTable#setSelectionMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSelectionMode(int))

Comment: I looked at both of your links, and I don't see anything in either of them about printing values from a linked list to a JTable. Maybe I am wrong, if so please direct me to where you see the solution to my problem in those links

Comment: Wrap the linked list in a `TableModel`, supply that `TableModel` to the `JTable`...

Comment: Okay, now that sounds like something that much help me. Can you elaborate a bit more on how to do that?

Comment: Something like [Creating a Table Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

Comment: Thanks guys. Trashgod's linked example is what really did it for me. I wish I could accept that as the answer but I don't know how