# Store products in a TreeSet and print the content in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tree, jtable

I'm trying to create a GUI which will let the user introduce and remove products in a GUI, by using a TreeSet. The user specifies the product name and the quantity, before choosing which operation to perform: add product or remove product.

My question is: how do I print a JTable that can be updated constantly each time the user adds or removes a product?

This is what I have so far. You'll also see the table content I'm planning to display. I don't know if I'm using the TreeSet right, but I'd appreciate any help.

```
  public class Warehouse implements Serializable {
        private int nrOfProducts = 0;
        private TreeSet<Product> products = new TreeSet<Product>();
        private JTable productsTable;
        private Object[][] entries = new Object[100][10];
        private String[] columnName = {"Product name", "Price", "In stock", "Understock", "Overstock"};

        public Warehouse() {

        }

        public Warehouse(Product product, int nrOfProducts) {
            this.nrOfProducts = 0;
            this.products = new TreeSet();
        }

        public void addProduct(Product newProduct) {
            products.add(newProduct);
            nrOfProducts++;
        }

        public void removeProduct(Product product) {
            products.remove(product);
            nrOfProducts--;
        }

        public int getNrOfProducts() {
            return nrOfProducts;
        }

        public void initFile() {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("products.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(products);
                oos.close();
            }
            catch(Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void readFile() {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("products.ser");
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                Product prod = (Product) ois.readObject();
                while (prod != null)
                    addProduct(prod);
                ois.close();
        }
        catch(Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        public void printProducts() {
            for (Product p: products) {
               // here's where I got stuck
            }
        }
    }
```

I'll also attach here the Product class:

```
public class Product implements Comparable {
    String productName;
    private int price;
    private int stock;
    private boolean understock;
    private boolean overstock;

    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(String productName, int price, boolean understock, boolean overstock, int stock) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.price = price;
        this.understock = understock;
        this.overstock = overstock;
        this.stock = stock;
        if (stock > 15) {
            this.overstock = true;
            this.understock = false;
        }
        else if (stock < 3) {
            this.overstock = false;
            this.understock = true;
        }
        else {
            this.overstock = false;
            this.understock = false;
        }
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        Product prod = (Product) obj;
        return (productName.compareTo(prod.productName));
    }
}
```

Comment: *"This is what I have so far."*  That code shows no attempt to use the table.  Surely you can get it further advanced than that!  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  (Only one public class, hard code some data to replace the serialized objects.) 3) But for this type of task I'd typically use a `DefualtTableModel` that provides functionality to add or remove rows..

Answer (score 2):

Extend [`AbstractTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). In this case, you can access the `TreeSet` in your implementation of `getValueAt()`, *et al.*, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) for `Map`. Because `TreeSet` implements `SortedSet`, the `toArray()` method will return a sorted array of `Product` based on your implementation of `Comparable`.