# Display tree map in gui java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, treemap

Firstly I am completely new to Java so please can you explain things as simple as possible!

So I have a treemap, the keys are dates which point to strings.

I want to display this on screen but am not sure how to do so.

I did come across JTable. After reasearching this I was confused as my columns were a string array (simply the titles of the two columns) whilst my data was a tree map. After looking further online I found I should [create a table model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) but after reading through this I didn't really understand what I needed to do. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be more specific about what you don't understand? Stack Overflow is a site for questions that have specific focussed answers - it is not suitable for giving general tutorials on broad topics.

Comment: Is that a part of a university class? Swing is dead.

Comment: Wow, it's going rather well as a walking dead, then!

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you want to display your content varies depending on your requirement or on how the information could be displayed in an user-friendly way.

JTable is a good approach, JTree also is a good approach, although, I see JTable as a more standard way to do it.

I came with an approach I implemented really fast trying to simplify all the complex stuff and to fulfill what I understood from your question:

```
public class TableExample {

//Asuming you have a treemap like this
static Map<Date, String> sampleMap = new TreeMap<Date, String>();

//Initialize the sample treemap with some values (this static block will execute the first time we run this app)
static {
    sampleMap.put(createBirthdayFromString("14/02/1990"), "Marcelo's Birthday");
    sampleMap.put(createBirthdayFromString("29/06/1989"), "Oscar's Birthday");
    sampleMap.put(createBirthdayFromString("21/04/1985"), "Carlos' Birthday");
}

//This will create a date object based on a given String
public static Date createBirthdayFromString(String dateAsString) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date convertedDate = null;
    try {
        convertedDate = formatter.parse(dateAsString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Print stacktrace and default to current Date
        e.printStackTrace();
        convertedDate = new Date();
    }
    return convertedDate;
}

public void init() {
    //Create the JFrame to display the table
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setTitle("My Table Example");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setSize(520, 520);

    //Then a panel to keep our Main frame available to display other contents
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setBounds(mainFrame.getBounds());
    myPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    myPanel.setVisible(true);

    //Add the panel to the frame
    mainFrame.add(myPanel);

    //You will need to specify the columns you want to display in your table, for this case:
    String[] columns = new String[] {"Birthday", "Name"};

    //Then you can create a table model with zero rows at the beginning
    //The table model will define how the data in your table would be displayed
    //As well as provide some useful methods if you want to add certain events or edition capabilities :)
    DefaultTableModel defaultModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);

    //Then you create your table based on your model
    JTable myTable = new JTable(defaultModel);

    //Then you will like to fill each table row with the data of your treemap

    //We iterate over your map to obtain the records
    for (Map.Entry<Date, String> entry : sampleMap.entrySet()) {
        defaultModel.addRow(new Object[] {entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()});
    }

    //Now add the table to your frame
    myPanel.add(new JScrollPane(myTable));

    //Set the frame visible
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Main method that will execute this example
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TableExample().init();
}   
}
```

Please let me know if this helps you or you have any doubt. Happy coding! :)

Comment: See also this [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) that `extends AbstractTableModel`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do! Your comments were really helpful too thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

A table model is responsible for managing the data that a JTable displays.

Entries in a JTable are referred to by row and column indexes, but a TreeMap does not have this kind of arrangement. We can still refer to entries in a TreeMap as if they were indexed, by iterating the entry set with a counter.

This is similar to, for example, iterating a linked list to retrieve an element by index.

To do the bare minimum, [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) only requires that `getRowCount`, `getColumnCount` and `getValueAt` are implemented.

If you need the model to be editable, then implementing it gets more complicated.

```
class TreeMapTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private TreeMap<?, ?> data;

    TreeMapTableModel(TreeMap<?, ?> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    private Map.Entry<?, ?> getEntryFor(int row) {
        int index = 0;
        for( Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : data.entrySet() ) {
            if( index == row )
                return entry;
            index++;
        }
        throw outOfBounds("row", row);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        Map.Entry<?, ?> entry = getEntryFor( row );

        switch( column ) {
            case 0: return entry.getKey();
            case 1: return entry.getValue();

            default: throw outOfBounds("column", column);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    private static IndexOutOfBoundsException outOfBounds(
            String parameter, int value) {
        return new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
            parameter + "=" + value);
    }
}
```