# JFreeChart: how to get coordinates of an XYItemEntity?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I've been stuck with this problem for quite some time. I need coordinates of certain points that belong to XYItemEntity. I'm drawing candlestick charts, and want to know what are the coordinates of open, close, high, low prices of the item. 
[image]

Is there any way to achieve that?

EDIT: The question is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801444/jfreecharthow-to-get-coordinates-of-a-chartentity-and-snap-mouse-cursor-to-the but since then I changed the approach. What I want to achieve is the following:
I'm drawing a Candelistick chart. As mentioned above I want the user to be able to "snap" mouse to one of the 4 values of the candle: high, low, open, close. In order to implement this feature I figured I would build a collection of Points on ChartPanel that would correspond to those values of all the candles currently being displayed. Then, by adding ChartMouseListener to the ChartPanel, in the chartMouseMoved method I would check if the cursor is in close proximity to any of those points. 
Here I add MouseChartListener to the ChartPanel:

```
chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new MyChartMouseListener());
```

In this method I want to check if the cursor is near any of the candles:

```
@Override
    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent chartMouseEvent) {
        int x = chartMouseEvent.getTrigger().getX();
        int y = chartMouseEvent.getTrigger().getY();
        getCandleCloseToCursor(x,y);
    }
```

How should my getCandleCloseToCursor method look like?

```
private Point getCandleCloseToCursor(int x, int y) {
        //return point that belongs to the candle near the x,y position;
        //either high, low, close, open position
        return null;
    }
```

Hopefully it's a little bit more clear now.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain why you want this; there may be another way.

Comment: @trashgod: edited, hopefully it's clear now :)

Comment: @trashgod: could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117317).

Answer (score 1):

A [`CandlestickRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/CandlestickRenderer.html) collects `ChartEntity` information in its implementation of `drawItem()`, but it lacks the resolution you want. The required geometry is calculated on the fly for each item and never stored explicitly. Absent an entirely new renderer, one approach would be to update an adjacent `JTable` with relevant data taken from the `OHLCDataset`. Give your [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) access to a `ChartMouseListener`, obtain a reference to the `OHLCDataset` dataset, and use its accessor methods to fulfill the `TableModel` contract, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513). The exact details depend on your requirements, but you may be able to leverage `JTable` [filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: I'm trying to understand your solution, but I'm failing. In order to obtain a reference to the OHLCDataset I would first need to hoover the mouse over the candle, wouldn't I? Then, the OHLCDataset accessor methods give me range and domain values, not the x, y coordinates which I need.

Comment: Correct; at a minimum, you'd need to rewrite [`drawItem()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/CandlestickRenderer.html#line.627) to collect additional `ChartEntity` objects. My suggestion is to work with the existing implementation and construct a table with a four rows (OHLC) and a column for each item of interest.

Comment: I guess you mean something like this? http://i.imgur.com/MzX5O7g.png But how would I then move the mouse cursor to the point on the chart having only domain and range values?

Comment: The `XYItemEntity` can tell you its coordinates in the dataset.

Comment: thx, I'll try to implement this.