# HashMap in JTable

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jtable

I'm having trouble making a JTable that incorporates a hashmap instead of a multidimensional array. I'm using my own custom table class and get an error on the constructor. Here's the code for that class:

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CustomTable extends DefaultTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames;
    private HashMap<Integer, Object[]> newData;

    public CustomTable(HashMap<Integer, Object[]> newData, String[] columnNames) {
        this.newData = newData;
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.length; }

    public int getRowCount() { return newData.size(); }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Object[] rowData = newData.get(row);
        return rowData[col];
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        Object[] rowData = newData.get(row);
        rowData[col] = value;

        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    public void removeRow(int row) {
        newData.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CustomTable.getRowCount(CustomTable.java:21)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(DefaultTableModel.java:224)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:124)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:106)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:86)
    at CustomTable.<init>(CustomTable.java:9)
    at ControlPanelUI.setupTable(ControlPanelUI.java:22)
    at ControlPanelUI.createRightCP(ControlPanelUI.java:106)
    at MovieStore.<init>(MovieStore.java:33)
    at MovieStore.main(MovieStore.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: share the error info !

Comment: (Not the question, but: You `removeRow` wont renumber. You assign `this.newData` twice. The `newData` field should probably be `final`. You may want to copy the mutable data in the constructor (and check for `null`). Oh, and check the keys match the row numbers.)

Comment: Updated Post with error info included. @jatDevta

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach based on this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation is don't use a HashMap. What is the point of the Integer as the key and then an Array as the data? The key will never be used in the model. Just Use an `ArrayList`.

Secondly, don't extend `DefaultTableModel`. That class already provides storage for the model and implementation of all the methods. There is no know to override all the methods again. Instead you should be extend `AbstractTableModel`.

Note your error message is referring to the `setDataVector(...)` method? You get this error because you are extending `DefaultTableModel`. If you instead extend `AbstractTableModel` the problem should go away.