# showing databases in jtable

Tags: java, database, jtable

I´ve got a question, I´m working on a app that shows some data in a jtable, but I have a little problem, here is the thing, I have 2 data databases to show in the same jtable, and I don´t know how to show both in the same table, one of the tables give me info about a product, like stock and price, but the other one give me the components that make the full product. some idea?

this are my two databases: BMAEFOL1 and BMAEMAL1

I use another one to show other info but it´s in Jlabels. BMAEPRL1

so..this is my code for the part of the jtable:

```
if(BSC.getText() != " "){

       String ST = BSC.getText();
       aux=1;

       String SSQL="SELECT * FROM BMAEPRL1 WHERE NMPROD ="+ST+" ORDER BY NMPROD";  /*BMAEMAL1*/

    try{ 
       Class.forName(driver);
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url2, user, pass);
        st = cn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);  


        rs = st.executeQuery("Select CODMAT, DESCRI, CANTID, PTOPED, PREULT  from BMAEMAL1 WHERE CODMAT ="+ST+" ORDER BY CODMAT");
        rs.next();
```

the CODMAT and DESCRI need to be from BMAEFOL1 and the others from BMAEMAL1.

thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about several databases or serveral tables in one database?

Comment: I am taking several databases to show in one jtable

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do (since it's not really explicit) :

1. Get the ResultSet from a first query in your first table with a **SELECT ***
2. Get the ResultSet from the second query using **SELECT *** too.
3. Create a Map or whatever to link the data together from the two tables
4. Add the column names to your header and set the data in the JTable (you can use [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) to get all columns names)

Is this what you want to achieve ?

Comment: yes!! That´s what I want! sorry for my bad explenation, English is it not my first languague and in my languague I could find the answer!

Comment: This related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) illustrates displaying a `Map` in a `JTable`.